# " command not found: evim " in terminal mac

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I noticed this problem in my terminal some time ago, but I did not find a solution, is there any suggestion to solve this problem please

Thanks :)

**My devise (MacBook Air M1)**
**system used macOS 13.0**

[image: Image of the problem in my terminal]

> vim --version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Jul 12 2022 16:34:31)
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-50
```

Comment: `head -1 .zshrc` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Vim with the `-y` flag is equivalent to calling `evim`:

```
$ vim -y
```

See `:help evim`.

If you prefer to type `evim` instead of `vim -y`, you can add an alias to your shell's configuration file:

```
$ echo 'alias evim="vim -y"' > ~/.zshrc
```

Now, your real problem seems to be that you have the string `evim` at the top of `~/.zshrc`. Could you show us the file's content?

```
$ cat ~/.zshrc
```